# Is there any way to know if an IBM MQ already has any JMS Listeners attached to it?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am working on an application which gets a list of queue details from a DB and spins up Spring `SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint` objects for them.

```java
for (final String queueName : queueList) {
    SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setId( "demo-" + i++ );
    endpoint.setDestination( queueName );
    endpoint.setConcurrency( jmsMessageConcurrency );

    endpoint.setMessageListener( message -> {
        queueController.recv( queueName, message );
    } );
    registrar.registerEndpoint( endpoint );
}
```

I am facing a problem where my container has only 5 threads active and the `queueList` has say 10 queues. Now only my 5 queues are getting listeners while the other 5 are sitting without listeners. Any ideas to resolve this?

I was thinking of spinning additional instance of the same code to address this, then the question is how do I know if a queue already has a listener. Is there any way to know that?

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to introduce a manual mechanism based on DB. I introduced a field in table that gets marked(lock) when ever a queue has listener attached, and the service will pick up queues that doesn't have a lock on them. The problem with that was the lock has to be released when the application stops, which is not always successful.

Comment: Are you asking how to question the queue manager to see who is using a particular queue? If yes, you can send a PCF Inquire Queue Status command to the queue manager and it will answer to show whether a particular queue is in use at that time. If you want to see the sort of answer you get, it is equivalent to the MQSC command `DISPLAY QSTATUS TYPE(HANDLE) ALL`, which you could try first to see if it is what you need. Let me know if I have interpreted your request correctly and I can write a fuller answer.

Comment: You could include a timestamp in your lock field and have the listener update it periodically, when your new listeners are looking for a queue with no listener they can include logic to test if the timestamp is older than the expected update frequency.

Comment: If you only expect a single listener on each queue you could configure the queue as exclusive, only the first process to open it will be successful so the newer processes could cycle through the list until they find a queue they can open.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot increase the thread limit?

Comment: @JoshMc - Thanks for the polling tip. We are working on an on prem infra, which has limited resource quota, but we can spin up more instances of the application. That's why I was looking in to this. Can you move the polling suggestion to an answer? I will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to know if object (a queue) in MQ is allready opened, and if listener is attach to it.

However given that you work with Spring, and your stated goal is to dynamically attach listener to q, you should work on that. And leave IBM MQ alone.

Instead using SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint you should look at JmsMessageListenerContainer which is underlying abstraction. In this example I am using DefaultMessageListenerContainer subclass to attach MessageListener to each q. Each DMLC Container is endless loop using configurable number of threads to poll a message.

In this example class, we will use a Spring bean which will spun as much DMLC containers as needed. Majority of configuration options should be injected in class as normal Spring IOC. I am using one thread per container - set by concurrency parameter. Maximum number of working containers is limited only by configuration/implementation of taskExector.

```
/** 
 * Simple service to attach DefaultMessageListenerContainer to a destination at runtime.
 * Init this class as Spring Bean and use 'listen' method.
 */
class DynamicListeningWithSpring implements DisposableBean {

  @Setter ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
  @Setter Executor taskExecutor
  @Setter PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
  @Setter String concurrency = "1";

  final ArrayList<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> cointainers = new ArrayList<>();

  /** attach listener to destination and start receiving messages */
  void listen(String destination, MessageListener listener) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();   
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    dmlc.setSessionTransacted(true);
    dmlc.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    dmlc.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    dmlc.setConcurrency(concurrency);        

    dmlc.setDestination(destination);
    dmlc.setMessageListener(listener);

    // init and start receiving
    containers.add(dmlc);
    dmlc.afterPropertiesSet(); 
    dmlc.start();              
  }

  void destroy() {
    for(DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc: cointainers) {
      dmlc.stop();      
      dmlc.destroy();
    }
  }
}



// inject instance of DynamicListeningWithSpring  in your code
class UsageExample {
   @Setter DynamicListeningWithSpring dlws;

   void use() {
     String destination = "X"
     dlws.listen(destination, (Message msg) -> {..});
   }
}
```

It is possible to achieve same behavior using JMS directly by using feature called "Asynchronously listener". That will end up even little bit more performant, as it is more efficient code path than Spring solution, which is doing message polling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my problem still exist with this solution, I have no means to achieve the multiple instances problem. Based on my research so far I get that the solution needs to be logical rather than based out on the jms. Thanks for the tip with async listeners, I will update my code accordingly.

Comment: @Reshmi proposed code will open as many listeners as listen method is invoked. There will be no "stalled" listeners. In this sense this code does not suffer from limitation stated in your question.